# Mostly offsite asset management (laptops/smartphones) - what is a good SaaS based solution?

Tags: laptop

Most of our company assets are offsite. Everyone either works at home or onsite at a customer. Most asset management/audit/remote control software concentrate on company LAN based assets. We don't need an NMS as we use OpenNMS in the internal network.

I was thinking of something like Altiris Client Management Suite but since everything is connected to the internet a SaaS based solution sounds like the ways to go. LogMeIn Central looks ok but not that comprehensive.

What do you guys use?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? How is LogMeIn not comprehensive ? Have you considered running a "normal" solution in a DMZ or externally hosted?

Answer (score 1):

I'm keeping a eye on Microsoft's new Windows Intune service for this purpose

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsintune/pc-management.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Labtech does all you need. You can deploy in-house, or as a SaaS.